Add a number, add a letter exactly twice
In the first puzzle add the same number exactly twice to get a country.
In the second puzzle add the same letter exactly twice to get a state.
The numbers/letters added may be rotated, and they may overlap.
It is possible to get more than one solution here as solvers can be quite imaginative. But I have only a single solution so far.


No partial answers please

I will start the proceedings:

 
 Using 7 twice I get NZ which is the two letter iso code for NEW ZEALAND.
 Using l twice I can get Il which is the two letter abbreviation for ILLINOIS.


You have it. There is another state also. In the south.
